# Tokens too big (slow network clients) - how to do lots of roles / claims?

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

The internet connection my clients use is extremely slow... smaller than dial up speed sometimes. Thus, if in my application I need a very large number of roles / claims, the cookie must be transmitted every time - and this would take longer than the actual web page to transfer to the server before the request can be processed (the client upload speed is 1/10th the speed of the download!!!). Is there a way to have the claims exist on the server, or rather, to have the IdentityServer client (the web application on the server) check IdentityServer for claims instead of having to send them all via a token?

Comment: Yes, look into claims transformation.

Comment: @BrockAllen I haven't seen this in the documentation anywhere. Do you have any links for me by chance? Thanks!

Comment: I'd google for it -- it's a concept and technique.

Comment: Roger... any specific pointers for C# / ASP.NET? I've seen several articles about this on MSDN. Is there a recommended methodology for this per your experience?

Comment: Just write some middleware for it.